# My css is not working when I upload it to my host

Tags: css

I am having an issue with the css on my website, I am a little new to coding and don't get what is wrong. When I work on my site I open the file location in chrome off of my computer's storage. It was working fine but when I uploaded it and checked it out. My style wasn't working? Here is the page that is not working: http://www.npratchtv.com/prices.html

Comment: Seems to me like it's working.

Comment: Please be specific about "style wasn't working" means.

Comment: what is specifically not working I see it fine ..

Comment: you stylesheet is correctly loaded. I can view the style.css. If your style.css is not updating correctly, you might just need to refresh your browser tab. Although depends on how you setup static path for public directory, you might not have complied your stylesheet correctly to take its updated effects, or your updated version of stylesheet is not located in the path you assigned from html

Comment: The weird thing is that the css is working for the menu bar but not for the pricing div

Comment: Just tested it and it works in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge but not Google Chrome????

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work, how it's supposed to look etc. Anyway, you have errors in your HTML such as curly quotes instead of straight quotes around attribute values. Run your page through a validator and fix all issues; that will likely make all problems go away.

Answer (score 0):

I ran my code through a validator and cleared my chrome cache and it works fine now... Im not sure which one helped but thanks for anyone who comments <3

Comment: But you still have the wrong quotes, the duplicate IDs etc. There''s no way the site now works the way it's intended.